# What does it mean if a "device administrator" can "change the screen lock"?

Tags: security, privacy, device-administrator

If a corporate policy requires a mobile device management app (like Microsoft Intune), what does it mean in Settings-> Security-> Device Administrators when "Change the screen lock" is listed?  Is that just changing the style of lock (passcode, fingerprint), or does that allow the administrator to disable the lock altogether (e.g. to unlock the phone to inspect the data or reset the passcode).

Comment: +1 - Good question. I would suppose the latter. Much like your corporate sysadmins can lock you out of your computer, given the right circumstances, they could lock you out of this device, too.

Comment: See if this gives you a broad idea: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#policies

Comment: Thanks Firelord, the link is indeed interesting, but is lacking that specific policy...

Answer (score 2):

It enables the app to change the lock code and lock you out of the device. In general trustworthy apps wpuldn't abuse this unless you request it. Like android device manager changing the code when you request it because of lost and stolen. Be careful with such a permission.